# tar directory and exclude multiple subdirectories

Tags: linux, tar

I'm trying to tar a whole directory except some subdirs..

The dir `my-base-dir` is zipped but the excluded dirs/files are also included?

```
tar -cf my-base-dir/bak/site/site.tar my-base-dir --exclude=my-base-dir/bak/db/* --exclude=my-base-dir/bak/site/*
```

The excluded paths are correct relative to the current working dir.. Because the output tar file is put in one of them

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to put `--exclude` option before the list of file names to put into (or get out of) the archive i.e.

```
tar --exclude='my-base-dir/bak/db/*' --exclude='my-base-dir/bak/site/*' -cf my-base-dir/bak/site/site.tar my-base-dir
```

or you can also use:

```
tar -cf my-base-dir/bak/site/site.tar --exclude='my-base-dir/bak/db/*' --exclude='my-base-dir/bak/site/*' my-base-dir
```

Comment: When i want to exclude content of the sub-directories inside uploads folder without excluding empty folders itself, can i do it without using --exclude-from file?
--exclude='/name/uploads/*/*' does not work.