# Unable to exclude directories while using tar

Tags: gnu-tar

I have a folder in Home directory with the following structure:

```
top-tree
+-- .git
+-- branch1
|   +-- branch11
    |   +-- .idea
    |   +-- branch111
    |   +-- branch112
    |   +-- branch113
    |   +-- branch114
        |   +-- branch1141
        |   +-- branch1142
        |   +-- branch1143
    |   +-- branch115
    |   +-- branch116
    |   +-- branch117
```

Now, I want to tar the entire contents but must exclude all the hidden directories like `.git` and `.idea` and one particular directory `branch114` which has at least 2 subdirectories (the number of subdirectories may vary from time to time).

I tried to do this by using the tar command with the following parameters:

```
tar -czvf archive.tar.gz --exclude=~/top-tree/branch1/branch11/branch114 --exclude=~/top-tree/.git --exclude=~/top-tree/branch1/branch11/.idea top-tree/

tar -czvf archive.tar.gz --exclude=~/top-tree/branch1/branch11/branch114 --exclude=~/top-tree/.*
```

But none of the above seems to work. Every single time, the entire contents of the folder `top-tree` is placed in archive.tar.gz. I've tried out a lot of things (so many that I can't quote here including [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32845/tar-exclude-doesnt-exclude-why) one) suggested in this website and others, played with the permutations of parameters etc. *But unlike other similar questions, mine seems like it's a problem with the path*. The tar version I'm using is 1.29. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: The --exclude option does not apply to `tar` but to GNU tar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tar directory and exclude multiple subdirectories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/481993/tar-directory-and-exclude-multiple-subdirectories)

Comment: at least one issue is that the exclude states an absolute path but the path to archive is relative, thus not the same path for (gnu)tar (even if it's the same path on the filesystem for the given cwd). Beside this, duplicate still applies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're archiving paths of the form `top-tree/stuff` and excluding paths of the form `/home/skrowten/top-tree/stuff`. Your exclusion patterns never match anything.

The simple solution is

```
tar -czvf archive.tar.gz --exclude=top-tree/branch1/branch11/branch114 --exclude=top-tree/.git --exclude=top-tree/branch1/branch11/.idea top-tree
```

Note that if there is e.g. a `top-tree/subdir/top-tree/.git` then this will be excluded as well. A trick to avoid this is to start the command line path with `./`, and rely on the fact that `.` will only ever appear at the root.

```
tar -czvf archive.tar.gz --exclude=./top-tree/branch1/branch11/branch114 --exclude=./top-tree/.git --exclude=./top-tree/branch1/branch11/.idea ./top-tree
```

If the leading `./` bothers you, add the option `--transform='s!^\./!!'` to the tar call.

Comment: I figured it must be something like this. You mean the exclude parameter must have `/top-tree` at the highest level and not `~/`, right? But unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't work as well. I'm pulling my hair here!

Comment: Oh right, no, tar doesn't do that. You need a relative path. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Great! It worked. But the path now is preceded by a `.` as in `./top-tree/` is the parent directory instead of `top-tree/` It would be nice if you add how to (1) make `top-tree/` the parent directory and (2) to exclude any hidden folder within `top-tree/`. Could yo do that?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit `--transform='s!^\./!!'`